# Using method in java

Tags: java, methods

I'm pretty new to java and currently trying to make a code using methods in which it would output "Welcome, Mr. David." Something like this. The salutation would come from the gender and status. I'm also trying to figure out how to do this "variable might not have been initialized". I tried to search for a fix, but it just put the word 'null' in the front of the name like this, "nullDavid".

```
package designingmethod;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DesigningMethod {
    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String name, m1, m2, m3, f1, f2, f3, sal, sex, status;
                
        m1 = "Mr.";
        m2 = "Mr.";
        m3 = "Sir";
        f1 = "Ms.";
        f2 = "Mrs.";
        f3 = "Ma'am";
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        System.out.println("Name:");
        name = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Sex(M/F):");
        sex = sc.next();
        System.out.println("Status(S/M/W):");
        status = sc.next();
        Greet(sal, name);

        
        if("M".equals(sex)){
            switch (status) {
                case "S":
                    sal = m1;
                    break;
                case "M":
                    sal = m2;
                    break;
                case "W":
                    sal = m3;
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }
        }
        if("F".equals(sex)){
            switch (status) {
                case "S":
                    sal = f1;
                    break;
                case "M":
                    sal = f2;
                    break;
                case "W":
                    sal = f3;
                    break;
                default:
                    return;
            }
    }
    }
    static void Greet(String name, String sal){
        System.out.println("Welcome, " + sal + name + ".");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your program simply considers that non of your if blocks is entered because there is no guarantee that the user enters either `"F"` or `"M"`. You could just initialize sal as an empty Stirng `sal = "";`. But you also call your method before you even have your logic to set the values and you pass your arguments in the wrong order. it should be `Greet(name, sal)` after your if-blocks, not what you currently have

Comment: Sal is being printed before it is given a value. Move your Greet,() call to after sal is set. Also Java convention is camel case for method names so it should be greet()

Comment: `sal` did not get any value before you used it for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are experiencing - "Variable 'sal' might not have been initialized" is because you are trying to use this variable before having any value assigned to it.

Currently, since you are defining the variable within the method body it doesn't have a default value, therefore its value in the case of String is null. You can see the difference when you for example initialize the sal variable right before calling the Greet(sal, name) method...

For example you can do it like that:

```
sal = "Test Value";
Greet(sal,name);
```

There are three main types of variables: local variable, class (static) variable, and instance variable. You might take a look [here](https://javajee.com/class-variables-instance-variables-and-local-variables-in-java#:%7E:text=Instance%20variables%20(non%2Dstatic),a%20class%20outside%20any%20methods.&text=Local%20variables%20are%20variables%20defined,within%20a%20method%20or%20block.) for a better understanding of your problem.